# Bedload discharge for canals of triangular cross-section

Tags: civil-engineering, hydraulics

All the methods I know of for calculating bedload discharge are for canals of rectangular cross-section (constant depth of flow). The bedload is first computed for a unit of width (using the constant water depth) and then multiplied by the width. However, I have an almost triangular cross-section, where the depth is not constant. How can I calculate bedload discharge in this case?